# cclocation concerns and clarifying on the subject

Tags: ios, xcode

Is collocation usually mean the location of the device? I am a little hazy on this subject.Or does mean general location.

Comment: Yes, it's of course the location of the device, it's unable to assume the location of anything else but itself :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `CLLocation`?. This is a class which represents location data generated from a `CLLocationManager` object.

Please refer to the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), in particular the [section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) on getting the user's location.